# How to insert image from database to JTable

Tags: java, database, image, swing, jtable

I try to insert my image from database to JTable but, it can't be shown. How can i overcome this problem?

```
public void loadData(ArrayList<Monster> monsters) {
    /**
     * Collection of Cell Example : Gondar 45 56 78 4 Axe 34 67 90 5
     */
    Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    for (Monster item : monsters) {
        Vector<String> dataRow = new Vector<String>();
        dataRow.add("" + new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/monster/"+item.getAvatarUrl())));
        dataRow.add("" + item.getName());
        dataRow.add("" + item.getHp());
        dataRow.add("" + item.getDp());
        dataRow.add("" + item.getAp());
        dataRow.add("" + item.getLevel());
        data.add(dataRow);
    }
    this.setDataVector(data, columnElement);
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable (instead of JDBC) take Icon from UIManager - UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon")

Answer (score 1):

1) Seems you get `Icon`'s from classpath not db. 
2) You need to add `ImageIcon` into `TableModel`, but you add `String` instead of that.

You can override `getColumnClass` method of your `TableModel` to return `Icon.class` for proper column and store `ImageIcon` in that column. For example:

```
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0,3){
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if(columnIndex == 1){
                    return Icon.class;
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        };
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(TestFrame.class.getResource("1.png"));
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"1",icon,"2"});

        JTable t = new JTable(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
    }

}
```

Here is 1 row in `TableModel` in second column stored `ImageIcon`,  and `JTable` knows how to display it with column class `Icon`.

[image]